# config nginx to access index and spec_runner pages

Tags: nginx, configure

index.html page could access, but not spec_runner.html.I want to access two different pages, one for app, another for tests. Could you help me? thanks, :).My configure is following

```
location ^~ /p/login      { rewrite .* /index.html last; }
location ^~ /specs        { index spec_runner.html; }

location ~* ^/(users|books) {
    proxy_pass http://api;                                                      
}                                                                             

location / {                                                                  
    root /home/user/project;                                    
    proxy_cache off;                                                            
    expires -1;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;                                         
    add_header Cache-Control private;                                          
}
```